# How to buy asset at lower price immediately (for market price)

Tags: trading

I want to buy asset, when it reaches lower price immediately (for market price). But buy-stop (stop market) or stop limit orders allows me to buy only when it reaches higher prices.

Answer (score 2):

An ordinary [limit order](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/04/022704.asp) allows you to buy only if the asset falls to a given price or lower.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know it is the lowest price?

Usually when the price is moving down it will continue moving down, that is why a buy-stop allows you to buy after rebounding off the lows and breaking through a line of resistance.

A stop-limit allows you to buy at your limit price or lower after it hits your stop price!